# "awk with if / substr " didn't work as expected

Tags: linux, awk

I want to filter the records where disk usage is greater than 70% using df and awk/if/substr. The problem is it looks like only the first character is considered when comparing:

**commands:**

```
# df -Pah | awk '{if(substr($5,1,length($5)-1)>70) print $5}'
Use%
9%
8%
```

But like this it works:

**commands:**

```
# df -Pah | awk '{if(substr($5,1,length($5)-1)-70>0) print $5}'
100%
100%
100%
# df -Pah | awk '{if(substr($5,1,length($5)-1)-30>0) print $5}'
54%
35%
100%
100%
100%
```

Does anyone know why?

PS: `df -Pah` output, in fact it's quit the same as `df -h`:

```
Filesystem  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2   2.0G 1020M  894M  54% /    
udev        4.0G  420K  4.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs       4.0G   16M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: And show us the output of `df -Pah`. (You may change the names of your devices and mount points if you consider them sensitive, but be sure to keep the layout correct.)

Comment: it should work in both, what OS are you using and awk version? change the `awk` condition to  `if(substr($5,1,length($5)-1)+0>70)` in order to force the result as numeric and see the result

Comment: @αғsнιη  this happened on CentOS7  and SuSE11.3 ,

Comment: but you didn't tell us if this doest works or not?! `if(substr($5,1,length($5)-1)+0>70)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk comparisons are as I recall either numeric or string comparisons, depending on the type of the left operand, and that would explain what you're seeing: `substr` gives a string result, and strings beginning 'U', '9', and '8' are all greater than any string beginning '7'.

Subtraction produces a numeric result.

Comment: No either if it's comparing first character it should not give result `print $5` only one num character length result!

Comment: sorry,i just copy the first 2 line.